# Retrieving File details in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to retrieve file details from files in the Program Files folder.
I receive an error while trying to retrieve file details.

```
Dim sFileName As String = ("%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe")
Dim Info As FileVersionInfo
Info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(sFileName)
Msgbox(Info.ProductName.ToString())
```

I receive file not found error at 3rd line.
But if I change the path from `"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe"` to `"c:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe"` it works fine.

What should I do if I want to retrieve file details from the path which includes a "%" character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't a Windows machine handy to test, but try [expanding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) the environment variable first:

```
sFileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(sFileName)
Info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(sFileName)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an environment variable:

```
Dim programFiles As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles")
Dim sFileName As String = Path.Combine(programFiles, "Windows Defender\MSASCui.exe")
```